# Styling IE9 Browser Mode with Document Mode IE7 standards

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-9, developer-tools

I've had a "bug" raised by a client using IE9 Browser Mode with Document Mode IE7 standards set (why it is set to this I don't know see attached image) [image: IE9 Browser Mode with Document Mode IE7 standards]

This is causing a styling error obviously and the client has requested I fix the error. I'm nearly 100% sure there is nothing I can do to target this sort of a set up and fix the problem. I'm using Modernizr to target the different browsers. I would like a robust answer to bring back to the client as to why this is a scenario I can't fix or if I am wrong and there is something I could do to rectify this then I would appreciate the help.

Thanks.

Comment: What sort of bug? IE9's IE7 mode emulates genuine IE7, though it's not perfect. Have you checked whether the same bug occurs in genuine IE7? Should your site support IE7?

Comment: IE9's IE7 mode does emulate IE7 (to a point) when set to Browser Mode: IE7 and Document Mode: IE7 standards but that wasn't my question. I was asking was there a way of targeting IE7 document mode while in IE9 Browser mode as opposed to IE7 Browser mode and IE7 document mode. The same bug doesn't occur in normal IE7 hence the question. What do you mean should the site support IE7, of course it should, why wouldn't it? Thanks for the comment though. I don't think the type of bug is important.

Comment: A lot of people don't bother to support IE7 these days, that's why I asked whether your site should support it. The only way a *normal user* would end up viewing your site in IE9's IE7 mode would be if they clicked the "compatibility mode" button. Adding `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` should prevent that button showing up. So, your question confuses me. If your client has literally gone in to the Developer Tools and changed the "Document Mode" to "IE7 Standards", and the bug does not show up in genuine IE7, then there's no point fixing this - the bug doesn't matter.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't believe there will be much you can do about this.  There are meta tags that enforce the standards but if the user opens up their developer tools and manually selects the settings then it's not really a problem worth looking into.

Answer (score 2):

I know this sounds weird.. but some people have document mode set to IE7 standards BY PAGE DEFAULT.

My mother's version of ie9 is set to IE7 standards. I highly doubt she did this herself and i have no memory of doing this even though i sometimes work on her machine when i visit. So it might be that certain people DO have ie9 set to a deprecated browser standard.. (7)

I think it's high time we stopped supporting 7 anyway. I'm a freelancer and if you want support for anything below ie8 i charge A LOT more. But now that i've run into this document mode issue - where it IS genuinely set to ie7 standards as page default.. i wonder how many people are browsing broken pages out there because of this...